# Is there a method to get a view to provide multiple tags in a CSV export within one column rather than mulitple rows?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a D7 site that is being recreated. I need to generate a CSV of particular fields used in its numerous content types.

There are 5 taxonomy reference fields. I have created a relationship for each.

The problem I'm encountering is that these fields each allow multiple terms, and Views handles this by creating a new row for each term (repeating the other information) rather than having all instances of the field's term values appear in one column

The result is that a site with about 25,000 nodes generates a view that dies after about 250,000 rows.

Is there some trick to do it?

Comment: Turning on aggregation and setting the term fields to `GROUP_CONCAT` may help significantly

Comment: @Clive indeed, aggregation solved the issue, though there wasn't a GROUP_CONCAT in D7, the default aggregation worked when I changed the default setting of TID to ENTITY ID. One odd thing is that I had tried that without success once, but I was using a relationship between the reference field and taxonomy. Removing the relationship and just using the node field, set to plain text, seemed to be part of the solution. You set me on the right path. Please put your comment in as an answer.